# Unexpected number of loops in while

Tags: wp-query, loop

I wanted to test how many times a while would loop through a query array.

```php
$WatchListArgs = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'category__and' => array( 4, 16 ),
);

$WatchListQuery = new WP_Query( $WatchListArgs ); 
$WatchListCount = $WatchListQuery->found_posts;
if ( $WatchListCount > 0 ) {
    echo '<h2>Watch List</h2>';

    if ( have_posts() ) {
        echo 'There are ' . $WatchListCount . ' Watch List posts';

        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            echo '*';
        endwhile;
    }
} // end if
```

The result was There are 1 Watch List posts************

Why are there 12 asterisks, instead of 1?

Note: I already understand that many developers don't like echo.

Comment: I'm not sure why my ''' for code isn't working correctly.

Comment: Need to use backticks (`\``), rather than single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `have_posts()` is for the main loop, and not your custom query. Prefixing each use of `have_posts()` and `the_post()` with `$WatchListQuery->` will fix it:

```php
if ( $WatchListQuery->have_posts() ) {
```

```php
while ( $WatchListQuery->have_posts() :
    $WatchListQuery->the_post();
```

Comment: This query is actually preceded by another query for Upcoming Conferences. I thought that a custom query object replaced the main loop. I think that is where the error in my thinking came in. These two query objects do not replace the main loop, the main loop is still there, it's just not used!

Comment: Magic! Not only did it fix the problem, it taught me something new about scope in the WordPress query object.